# A way to validate session cookies without storing them

Tags: security, session, cookies, hash, backend

## Basic info

- I have a webserver with all that fancy stuff.
- It runs on my half-potato PC, so I don't have any free 64TB of SSD storage.
- I have to care about scalability, because one day I might have a **1000** users.

  > **Wow, such users, very a lot!**
- I don't want any passwords to be stolen if user will lose his device. So I decided to use sessions.
- I don't want to store all of the user sessions, because that can be possibly a **100** of devices. So `1000 * 100` is a lot of session cookies.
- I thought about a way *not to store*, but to *validate* sessions to check if request is from the owner of the account.

## Structure

#### Global

```js
// Secret 128 bytes array.
const ByteArray serverMagic;

// Generates a SHA512 hash based on data.
function hash(ByteArray data);

// Encodes array of bytes into base64 string.
function base64(ByteArray data);

// Returns current time on the server.
function getCurrentDate();

// Returns userMagic based on the user ID.
function getUserMagic(Integer uid);

// Returns true if user entered wrong password.
function isLoginInvalid(Integer uid, String password);
```

```js
function Object.toShortString(); // Encodes an object into a short ASCII string.
```

#### For each user

```js
const Integer uid; // User ID.
var String password; // Secret code that gives you all of that damn power.
var ByteArray userMagic // Secret 128 bytes array.
```

## Logic

#### If user wants to log in

he will send:

- Session expiration date (so cookie won't be valid after a desired amount of time)
- User ID
- Password (or hash of the password, it doesn't really matter)

```js
function logIn(Date expire, Integer uid, String password) {
  if(isLoginInvalid(uid, password)) then
    return error;

  String encExpire = expire.toShortString();
  String encUID = uid.toShortString();

  ByteArray userMagic = getUserMagic(uid);

  ByteArray food = encExpire + '_' + serverMagic + userMagic + '_' + encUID;
  ByteArray hash = hash(food);

  String session = encExpire + '_' + encUID + '_' + base64(hash);
  return session;
}
```

Client will save that session cookie.

#### If user will make some action

he will send a session cookie to the server.

```js
// After parsing session cookie
function request(Date sessionExpire, Integer uid, ByteArray sessionHash) {
  if(sessionExpire < getCurrentDate()) then
    return error;

  String encExpire = sessionExpire.toShortString();
  String encUID = uid.toShortString();

  ByteArray userMagic = getUserMagic(uid);

  ByteArray food = encExpire + '_' + serverMagic + userMagic + '_' + encUID;
  ByteArray hash = hash(food);

  if(hash == sessionHash) then
    return success;
  else
    return error;
}
```

#### If user will want to invalidate all sessions

due to device loss or password change server can just generate a new `userMagic`, that will make all of the previous session cookies invalid.

## Questions

- Is it a good way <s>to store</s> not to store sessions?
- Is there a flaw in my system?
- Can it be cracked?

  - And how can it be cracked?
- How can it be abused?
- How can I improve my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Revised answer:

The problem with solutions like this is that they are often vulnerable to very subtle bugs, such as [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).  Play it safe and use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code) instead.

FYI .Net has some construction that is not too different than this, but uses HMAC and no user magic.

### Previous, retracted answer:

Any user can compute:

```
String session = encExpire + '_' + encUID + '_' + base64(hash);
```

Which means any user can create arbitrary sessions.  The hacker is going to do this with encUID set to the administrator uid, which may 1 or 0 or something like that.

I could potentially suggest fixing this bug using HMAC with a secret key, but you really should not be implementing this yourself.  Find a widely used and well studied library that does session management for you rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Well, any user can compute that. But the thing is that the new hash is being generated for every session. Plus hash uses 2 secret values, that never leave the server machine. `ByteArray food = encExpire + '_' + serverMagic + userMagic + '_' + encUID;` So, as i understand, user will need to generate an equal hash. To do that he will need to either get the secret values (he can't) or try 2^256 times to generate SHA512 hash or reverse the SHA512 hash. That is the catch. In the secret values. Thank you for your answer. But if you think I'm missing something can you correct me?

Comment: @DanilOzerov Sorry I see your point, so my answer was incorrect.  However, it may be vulnerable to [length extension attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_extension_attack).  HMAC prevents this.